# If Jesus is God the Father, did God the father die on the cross when Jesus died?

Tags: life-of-jesus, nature-of-god, crucifixion

Most Christians believe Jesus is God. Scripture says there is one God, the Father. If this is so, when Jesus died on the cross did God the Father die also?

Comment: Welcome Bertrand.  Unfortunately, this question isn't a good fit for this site: answers to it will be mere opinions, and here we try to explain and learn what specific groups of Christians believe.  If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: Not a truth question. Capable of being answered from the POV of Trinitarians, which is obviously what the OP wants, without claiming that Trinitarians are correct. Edited to make this clearer.

Comment: I (further) adjusted the wording as per @DJClayworth's suggestion.  If that is not was intended, please feel free to re-edit.

Comment: Wait, why was this question about Trinitarians? The original version (before @DJClayworth's edit) didn't say that at all. It could just as well be asking for a Unitarian perspective--and in fact, that would be *my* assumption, given the premise of the question.

Comment: I took the (possibly contentious) action of rolling back to the OP's original, because I don't believe it's at all obvious that the OP is asking about a Trinitarian perspective. I think we need the OP to clarify, rather than trying to read into the question.

Comment: @Flimzy In that case, it again becomes a too broad/"truth question" scenario and should be closed.

Comment: @ThaddeusB: I agree. It needs to be closed until the OP can clarify what they mean. Hopefully they will do so!

Comment: I believe this question is [now] asking about the heresy of [Patripassionism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patripassianism). There are [a couple of questions on that](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=patripassionism), both of which are relevant.

Comment: How is this question off topic?

Comment: Related: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/23157/35851

Answer (score 3):

Most Trinitarians use this to summarize the Trinity:

1. The Father is God
2. The Son is God
3. The Holy Spirit is God
4. The Father, the Son, and the Holy Spirit are all distinct (not one of them is identical to the other).

Therefore, when Jesus died on the cross, God the Father did not also die on the cross.