# How is the trinity all God but also distinct?

Tags: nature-of-god, trinity

In an answer to [If Jesus is God the Father, did God the father die on the cross when Jesus died?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/44071/if-jesus-is-god-the-father-did-god-the-father-die-on-the-cross-when-jesus-died) it is pointed out that:

> to summarize the Trinity:
>
> 1. The Father is God
> 2. The Son is God
> 3. The Holy Spirit is God
> 4. The Father, the Son, and the Holy Spirit are all distinct (not one of them is identical to the other).
>
> Therefore, when Jesus died on the cross, God the Father did not also die on the cross.

I really want to understand this but I really have a problem understanding the whole concept.  How can the Father, the Son, and the Holy Spirit all be God and also be distinct from each other? This is contradictory to me.

After reading [What is the meaning of 'is' in the context of the Trinity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/53289/35851) which was indicated as a possible duplicate in the comments, the top accepted answer shows the contradiction I am talking about.

If the Father is God and the Son is God, then surely the Father is also the Son.  But as I have seen it, and is pointed out in the answer to the first question, and indicated in the diagram in the answer to the "possible duplicate" the Father and Son are distinct from each other.

In answer to [Is there a hierarchy in the Trinity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/2881) @warren said

> God has distinct persons making up His one self - Father, Son, and Holy Spirit.

This could imply that they are one and the same because God was within Jesus whilst He was among us, but God is within us too, is he not?

Genesis 1:26 mentioned in [What is the Biblical basis for the doctrine of the Trinity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/72) mentions that God said

> Let us make man in our image, after our likeness: and let them have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over the cattle, and over all the earth, and over every creeping thing that creepeth upon the earth. - KJV

because Jesus was with God in heaven when God created Adam.

Sola Gracia said in [What qualifies the 3 entities of the Trinity as one?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/57938/what-qualifies-the-3-entities-of-the-trinity-as-one)

> Put simply, 'trinity' describes something of the intrinsic nature of God; 'one' describes the numeric total of essences that are called God and have the attributes of God: there being but one, (Deut 6:4) who is known variously by titles YHVH, the God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob, etc.

How do you reconcile the trinity of the Father is God, the Son is God and the Holy Spirit is God when

> yet for us there is one God, the Father, from whom are all things and for whom we exist, and one Lord, Jesus Christ, through whom are all things and through whom we exist. **- 1 Corinthians 8:6**

Comment: Hi Chris.  At the root this question still sounds very much like the "meaning of is" question, so I'm closing it as a duplicate.  However, you may be able to tease out additional insight in follow-up questions, akin to your last one (on reconciling 1 Co 8:6 with trinitarianism).  At the end of the day the exact nature of God in trinitarianism is something of a mystery to us, but trinitarians believe it on the basis of associated Scripture, and submit to its authority over human reason.