# Why didn't the universe fall apart when Jesus died?

Tags: life-of-jesus, protestantism, death, providence, colossians

In Colossians 1:16-17, it talks about how the world was made by Jesus and for Jesus. But it also says that "He is before all things, and in him all things hold together", so why didn't we all die and the universe, fall apart when Jesus died as it says that "in him all things hold together". Does this mean that Jesus's death wasn't fully death?

It's alright if you aren't a Protestant and you answer the question but it would be preferable to hear an answer from a Protestant.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Your question is an interesting one. However, for it to be on-topic at this site, it needs to specify what group or denomination of Christians (such as Catholics or Lutherans) tha you wish to hear an answer from. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) You can edit your question to add the denominational perspective you're interested in hearing.

Comment: Related, if not actually the answer: [Was the Trinity still the Trinity when Jesus died?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/23187/1377) — "His body died, but his soul — with its divine nature as well as human — continued its existence. The Word did not die."

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that is a pretty good answer that seems to satisfy me ;) Thanks again!

Comment: This question is based on a misunderstanding of Colossians. I think a better way to resolve this question would be to ask "How do protestants interpret Colossians 1:16-17 mean?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering the question from Evangelical Protestant perspective.

The reason the universe didn't fall apart when Jesus died is that death does not mean "cessation of existence."

> For as the body apart from the spirit is dead, so also faith apart
>   from works is dead.
>
> James 2:26 (ESV)

James 2:26 says that death is a separation of body and spirit. Both do not undergo annihilation after death. Rather, both merely separated.

Other Bible verses agree:

> . 2 I know a man in Christ who fourteen years ago was caught up to the
>   third heaven—whether **in the body or out of the body** I do not know,
>   God knows. 3 And I know that this man was caught up into
>   paradise—whether **in the body or out of the body** I do not know, God
>   knows—
>
> 2 Corinthians 12:2-3 (ESV)
>
> Yes, we are of good courage, and we would rather be **away from the
>   body and at home with the Lord**
>
> 2 Corinthians 5:8 (ESV)

This is perfectly attested in the death of Jesus Christ:

> Then Jesus, calling out with a loud voice, said, “Father, into your
>   hands I commit my spirit!” And having said this he breathed his last.
>
> Luke 23:46 (ESV)

At Jesus' death, his spirit did not cease.Rather, he commited his spirit to his Father.

> Nicodemus also, who earlier had come to Jesus by night, came bringing
>   a mixture of myrrh and aloes, about seventy-five pounds in weight.
>
> John 19:38 ( ESV)

On the other hand, Jesus' body was buried.

### Conclusion

Jesus, being God who became flesh, identifying with our limitation by his own choice (John 1:1,14; Phil. 2:6-7) to save us (Matthew 1:21) ,was not the only person who is fully God. The Father and the Holy Spirit, his co-equals do exist (Matthew 28:19) to take hold of the universe.Jesus is both God and Man ( Col. 2:9) and his death is 100% real.

References:

http://www.gotquestions.org/absent-from-the-body.html

https://carm.org/soul-cease-exist-after-death